# Delete Excel Rows that contain certain word with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that contains hundreds of rows and I want to delete all the rows that are in column "L" in which the word "SAGI" is said (it stands for one kind of paperwork in the company I work for), in that same cell there is usually a small description of what to do with that SAGI, so filtering is not an option as there are too many descriptions.

I want to creat a Macro that can find and delete those rows every time I click it.

I found this tutorial helpful 
http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/06/21/fast-way-to-find-and-delete-excel-rows/  But I can't get to record it as a macro, so I tried programming it in VBA.

There is one comment that says how to create a VBA module for it which would look like this
[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqdIP.jpg)
But I end up getting that error and if I debug it, it points me to the second line.

This is my first time programming anthing mildly complicated in VBA and I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: lots of good answers here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/300330-vba-delete-entire-row-if-contains-certain-text.html

Comment: VBA is not really the ideal candidate for this. Unless 1-click vs 5 or 6 clicks is really critical for you for some reason (or you have to do it like 10+ times a day)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use this VBA function:

```
Sub RemoveRows(value As String)
Dim row As Long
row = 1
Do While row <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("L:L").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    If InStr(1, ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 12).Text, value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 12).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        row = row + 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub

Sub test()
    RemoveRows "SAGI"
End Sub
```

Comment: Where would I insert the specific word in that code?  Also if  (value As String) I can't get to save it

Comment: To test it, go the the procedure and press F5 inside the teste() sub.

Comment: I added the test sub on code :)

Comment: You can add a button too and call the code passing the parameter you want. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/assign-a-macro-to-a-form-or-a-control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub SAGIKiller()
    Dim N As Long, ToBeKilled As Range
    Dim i As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        If InStr(1, Cells(i, "L").Value, "SAGI") > 0 Then
            If ToBeKilled Is Nothing Then
                Set ToBeKilled = Cells(i, "L")
            Else
                Set ToBeKilled = Union(ToBeKilled, Cells(i, "L"))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not ToBeKilled Is Nothing Then
        ToBeKilled.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```